# python Regex for mixed alpha numerica data and special characters

Tags: regex, python-regex

I am trying to write a regex for the following use cases in a one line regex.

ex:

Table 1-2: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

Table 1: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

Table 1 this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

Table 1-2-1: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

similarly

Figure 1-2: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

Figure 1: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

Figure 1 this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

Figure 1-2-1: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)

i tried the following approach

```
import re
re.sub(r'^Table ()|([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|[0-9]+|[0-9 ]+)', " ", text_to_search)
re.sub(r'^Figure ()|([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|[0-9]+|[0-9 ]+)', " ", text_to_search)
```

Well this is not so good approach, also looking to eliminate the dependency of Table and Figure.
Please do suggest. Thanks in advance for your time.

Expected Output:

```
['Table', '1-2:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
['Table', '1:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
['Table', '1', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
['Table', '1-2-1:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']

['Figure', '1-2:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
['Figure', '1:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
['Figure', '1', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
['Figure', '1-2-1:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']
```

I am looking for the value available at list[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work to match everything listed in your "Expected Output"

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s([-0-9]+:?)\s(.*\))$')
matches = re.findall(pattern, text_to_search)
print(matches)
```

However, if what you really want is `['Table', '1', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']` or `['Figure', '1', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']`

(I'm guessing this is what "I am looking for the value available at list[2]" means)

then this pattern should work...

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s(\d+)\s(.*\))$')
```

Comment: Hi @JRiggles, Thanks for your time. i will run this and check. one doubt the '?' is to mark/mention optional?

Comment: will it be possible to write a regex for "Table this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)" and/or "Table 1-2: this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)" ... split as ['Table', '', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)'] and/or ['Table', '1-2:', 'this is a sample text 2 and some hyphen - (abbreviation)']

Comment: If you're referring to this part of the pattern `([-0-9]+:?)`, the `?` after the colon `:` means "match zero or one of the preceding character. I.e. the colon is optional, but there shouldn't be more than one if it's present.

Comment: For your second question: Yes, that should be doable - you'd rewrite this group `([-0-9]+:?)` as `([-0-9]*:?)`, changing the `+` to a `*`. That way it matches "zero or more of..." instead of "one or more of", essentially making the numerical/hypen part optional. Bear in mind this will match a colon `:` by itself.